# Compressing a database to a single file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, database-design, clickonce

In a contact manager program I've been storing data in CSV files for each contact and would like a way to compress this data into a single file.

I have attempted using data entry tools in the visual studio toolbox and template class, though I have never quite figured out how to use them. What would be especially convenient is if I could somehow store a generic class instance as opposed to having to come up with a string representation of it, and then parse it.

I'd also need to figure out how to tell the program what to do when a file is opened (I've noticed in the properties how to associate a file type with the program though am not sure how to tell it what to do when it's opened).

Comment: Are you asking a question here?

Comment: Yes...how do I tell it what to do when a file is opened, and how can I go about shrinking the data into one file effectively...
maybe if I elaborate...I realize I didn't say some things I meant to:
I don't know anything about SQL though it is commonly recommended, and can I store an object in an SQL data field as opposed to a string?

Comment: Guys I am sorry about the ambiguity of this question...I just didn't know how better to put it...partly because I was looking for how to use "binary serialization" before I knew what the term was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, switch to [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). You'll be able to query faster, compress it, and much more then working with a csv file.

Comment: I don't have one csv file, I have many, one for each contact, and a folder for notes which are stored in a text file for each note.

This appears off hand to be a program as opposed to a tool for visual studios...and I'd have no idea how I could use it in my scenario...(personally i'd prefer to keep everything within the capabilities of the express edition I all ready have. They have data tools, I'm just not sure how to use them...)

Comment: Looking back on my old posts, lol. This would have been the better answer

Answer (score -1):

Found this article about Serialization and it works very well!

http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/Nimusoft/Serialization105022008052559AM/Serialization1.aspx

edit: Figured I should probably post more. I have a class IOwner, and list of this class contains all of my database. So I added serialization tags to this class and others it references then substitute in those properties with the ones shown on the article:

```
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary
Imports System.IO
Namespace BinarySerialization
    <Serializable()> _
    Public Class IFile
        Implements ISerializable
        Public Contacts As List(Of IOwner)
        Public Self As IOwner
        Public Cars As List(Of Vehicle)
        Public path As String
        Public Sub New()

        End Sub
        Public Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
            Data.Self = info.GetValue("Self", GetType(IOwner))
            Data.Contacts = info.GetValue("Contacts", GetType(List(Of IOwner)))
            Data.Cars = info.GetValue("Cars", GetType(List(Of Vehicle)))
        End Sub
        Public Sub WriteFile()
            Dim s As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
            Dim B As New BinaryFormatter()
            B.Serialize(s, Me)
            s.Close()
        End Sub
        Public Function ReadFile() As IFile
            Dim Fs As New FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            Dim F As New BinaryFormatter()
            Dim s1 As IFile = DirectCast(F.Deserialize(Fs), IFile)
            Fs.Close()
            Return s1
        End Function
#Region "ISerializable Members"
        Public Sub GetObjectData(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext) Implements ISerializable.GetObjectData
            info.AddValue("Self", Data.Self)
            info.AddValue("Contacts", Data.Contacts)
            info.AddValue("Cars", Data.Cars)
        End Sub
#End Region
    End Class
End Namespace
```

**UPDATE 2016**

Binary serialization is not advisable for complex structures that are subject to change. Using a database storage method such as `SQLite` and using an ODB (object database model) would have been preferable.